# For loop to get the total of all iterations in Javascript, using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to get the total of iterations in a for loop on Javascript using node.js. Here is my code

```
var sum = 0;
for (itr=1; itr<=5; itr++) {
    var lt = 8;
    var sum = sum+lt;
    console.log(sum);
}
```

So what I get here is a list of values as the output. How do I get the last value (the total of all iterations) 40 as a single output. Can someone please guide me through this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move `console.log(sum)` outside your loop. Like this

```
var sum = 0;
for (itr=1; itr<=5; itr++) {
    var lt = 8;
    var sum = sum+lt;
}
console.log(sum);
```

BTW, two possible improvements:

1. remove the `var` in `var sum = sum+lt;`
2. make your iteration variable `var`, like this: `for (var itr=1; itr<=5; itr++) {`